# Imprimir arreglo de métodos en ruby

Tags: ruby

Suponiendo que tengo dos métodos y los agrego a un arreglo

```
def test1
  puts "foo!"
end

def test2
  puts "bar!"
end

arr = [method(:test1), method(:test2)]
```

Cómo le hago para imprimirlos correctamente, pues si los llamo con

```
arr* ","
```

o mediante

```
arr.join(",")
```

Obtengo `#,#`.

### **Ideal**

Me gustaría que se imprimiera su código fuente algo así:

`"def test1\n      puts "foo!"\n    end,def test2\n      puts "bar!"\n    end"`

### Actualización

Si uso

```
puts File.read(arr[0].source_location[0])
```

obtengo

> Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - (irb)
>          from (irb):12:in `read'
>          from (irb):12
>          from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/irb:11:in`'

Answer (score 1):

```
def test1
  "foo!"
end

def test2
  "bar!"
end

irb(main):043:0> arr= [test1, test2]
=> ["foo!", "bar!"]

irb(main):044:0> arr.join(",")
=> "foo!,bar!"

irb(main):045:0> arr* ","
=> "foo!,bar!"
```

Comment: con el puts me da cadenas vacías... as´´i que no sirve mucho :/

Answer (score 0):

No soy del mundo de Ruby como tal, pero buscando por ahí dí con una URL que podría interesarte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190146/in-irb-can-i-view-the-source-of-a-method-i-defined-earlier

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: `puts File.read(method(:test1).source_location[0])` me da read: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - -e (Errno::ENOENT) from

Answer (score 0):

El fallo que estás teniendo es porque estás trabajando desde la consola de Ruby, en vez de trabajar en un archivo de texto.

Aprovechando la información que has buscado, podrías implementar un método como el siguiente:

```
def source_method(name)
  # Obtener archivo y linea de la definicion
  file, line = self.method(name).source_location
  # Leer archivo
  lines = File.readlines(file)
  # Buscar metodo
  code = lines[line-1]
  (line...lines.size).each do |l|
    code << lines[l]
    break if lines[l].include?("end\n") &&
      lines[l].size - 4 == lines[line-1].split('def')[0].size
  end
  code
end
```

Con el siguiente código:

```
arr = [source_method(:test1), source_method(:test2)]
p arr.join(',')
puts arr
```

La salida sería la siguiente:

```
"def test1\n  puts \"foo!\"\nend\n,def test2\n  puts \"bar!\"\nend\n"
def test1
   puts "foo!"
end
def test2
  puts "bar!"
end
```

Saludos.

Comment: `readlines': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - -e (Errno::ENOENT) from `source_method' from `

Comment: comprendo que se debe a estar en la consola, pero lo que me interesa es trabajar en la consola, ¿es que los métodos que defines en consola se pierden cuando la cierras?.

Comment: Si, la consola solamente mantiene un historial de lo que has escrito, pero los métodos, variables asignadas, etc, no se almacenan. Lo habitual es escribir el código en un archivo, y ejecutarlo: `ruby archivo.rb` La consola se suele utilizar para hacer pruebas.